# Primefaces LineChart into PDF

Tags: jsf, pdf, canvas, primefaces

I'm working on a Primefaces based project and I want to export a chart in PDF.

```
<p:chart widgetVar="chart" type="line" model="#{managedBean.chart}" style="height: 500px; width: 99%;"/>
```

I'm using itextpdf (http://itextpdf.com/) to create my PDF.

I know that charts are canvas based but I don't really know how to manage this issue.

Feel free to ask me questions if you need more.

Comment: Break down your (very broad) problem. The chart is visually created client-side. So step one is how to get the chart from the client to the server. The chart can be exported as an image. So the question is how to get an image from the client to the server. The image is 'data' that can be put in a (hidden) field or send to the server via ajax. There are several q/a on Stackoverflow on that. Many of them not jsf, pdf, canvas or PrimeFaces related (and certainly not java-se). Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm working on it, seems a good idea, thanks a lot !

Comment: Check out this tutorial http://blog.hatemalimam.com/export-primefaces-charts-to-pdf/